# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - hide file from queue after upload done responce

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin and my configuration is:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},                
    url: 'assets/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/',
    done: function (e, data) {
        //some code
    }
});
```

When one file upload is done, I need to hide this file from list in `done:` event, but I cant get index of this file in queue list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution regarding my question.

`jQuery Fileupload` returns data on `done` event, which contains `context` parameter per uploaded thread, which is relevant to DOM element and can be used for any manipulations like hiding in my case:

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},                
    url: 'assets/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/',

    done: function(e, data) {
        //hide completed upload element in queue
        $(data.context['0']).fadeOut(700);

        //here isoutput of uploaded objects
        console.log(data.result);
    }
});
```